# CI Basic Routing

Tags: codeigniter

I have a route in my route.php :

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'ix/$1';
```

It routes URI such as `localhost/somename/admin/home` to  `localhost/somename/ix/home.php` controller.

The problem is if the URI is like this : `localhost/somename/admin/blog/updates`  (nonexistant function), rather than returning 404, it will just run the blog controller construct code.

How do I avoid this? One option is to add the routing to accept only necessary parameters, but is there any other way?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to clear up the question.  `admin/blog/updates` should load `ix/blog/updates` based on your route.  This would be looking for a `blog` function in the `ix` controller, so I'm not sure where "blog controller construct code" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `remap` function to route the controller internally:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array())
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method))
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
    }
    show_404();
}
```